Uploading file via NightwatchJS results in "File not found"
I am having trouble uploading a jpg file into a Drupal form, and cannot work out why, or how best to debug it. My code appears to confirm the file is there, but NightwatchJS disagrees.
The snippets of code around this look like:
Get and test the file
let path = require("path").resolve(__dirname + '/../../../../../../../modules/custom/test_folder/assets/image.jpg');
console.log(path);
console.log('** test: ', fs.existsSync(path))

The upload commands I am testing
.uploadFile('.form-managed-file__main input[type="file"]', require('path').resolve(path))
// .setValue('.form-managed-file__main input[type="file"]', require('path').resolve(path))

Both of these return similar errors

Error   Error while running .uploadFile() protocol action: invalid argument: File not found : unknown command: session/7c893475ca097b82470f980a18c87ab8/se/file

(Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.103)
(Driver info: chromedriver=106.0.5249.61 (511755355844955cd3e264779baf0dd38212a4d0-refs/branch-heads/5249@{#569}),platform=Linux 6.5.0-27-generic x86_64)
TimeoutError
An error occurred while running .uploadFile() command on <.form-managed-file__main input[type="file"]>: invalid argument: File not found : unknown command: session/7c893475ca097b82470f980a18c87ab8/se/file
(Session info: headless chrome=106.0.5249.103)
(Driver info: chromedriver=106.0.5249.61 (511755355844955cd3e264779baf0dd38212a4d0-refs/branch-heads/5249@{#569}),platform=Linux 6.5.0-27-generic x86_64)

Is there anything special I need to do to get to work in Docker?  Or maybe just some steps to debug, as existsSync says the file is there (returns true), but nightwatch says it isn't.  I have gone through forum posts, but most comments are quite old, and also don't appear to help resolve this.
Thanks for any tips,
Dan
